# Dealing with non-flat, unbounded data on a single observation

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, data-preprocessing

I'm currently trying to generate a number of (rudimentary) models to perform classifications (or get probability distributions through classifications).

Let's say that I have a particular video from YouTube:

[UMVC3 Grand Final AGE ChrisG vs TA Marvisto - Next Level Battle Circuit #3 Tournament](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njguvivB2Pw)

Going through [version 3 of the YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) I'm able to get the following Freebase topic ids about the video:

```
"topicDetails": {
    "topicIds": [
        "/m/0h1gqk6",
        "/m/0ffvx_"
    ]
}
```

- [/m/0h1gqk6](http://freebase.com/m/0h1gqk6) - Ultimate Marvel vs. Capcom 3 (correct indicator)
- [/m/0ffvx_](http://freebase.com/m/0ffvx_) - Battle Circuit (incorrect indicator, different topic)

As you can see, `topicIds` is an array.  There's no upper bound.

Now when trying to create an observation for either evaluation into a statistical model, or generating a statistical model, I don't know how to include the `topicIds` in the observations.

I had the following ideas:

**`Topic1`, `Topic2`, `Topic3` ... `TopicN`**

I've only ever seen four topics at most on a tag, so I could have say, ten variables on an observation.

However, the variables `Topic1` ... `TopicN` have an implication on the positioning.  It's possible that the `/m/0ffvx_` topic id would be moved into the third slot, affecting the processing of the model (since a particular topic id may be spread out among multiple columns).

**Binary classification variables**

I could have a separate variable for whether *every* tag is observed.  Something like:

```
Has_Freebase_TopicId_/m/0h1gqk6
Has_Freebase_TopicId_/m/0ffvx_
```

Where I would set it to true if that topic ID exists, false otherwise.  This solves the problem above of not properly capturing the observation for that topic ID, but it poses the following problems:

- If a new topic ID is observed, then there's nothing I can do about it. I don't think it's an issue anyways, as a model can't classify variables it's never observed, I can just quantify if it has something observed or not and use that.
- Currently, I have distinct 1,571 topic IDs, and there's a potential for many, many more.  The current model I'm using (Maximum Entropy Model) can handle this many variables, but this is for one unbounded variable in the data I'm observing.

Ultimately, this will be used to generate a maximum entropy model which will take the topic IDs (whatever the form) as well as other data points (some of it that requires dimension reduction, some that does not) and produce a probability distribution for a classification.

Is there a better way to observe this kind of data which captures all of the data points?

Comment: Your thoughts about what kind of "statistical model" you are developing, and why, would be welcome, because they might suggest appropriate methods to encode your `topicIds` data.

Comment: @whuber See the second to last paragraph, I hope that's the clarification you were looking for.

Comment: As far as storing the data, you should IMO have one row for every video-tag pair in the dataset. This prevents needing to worry about if a video has more than X tags (which is basically having the data in whats called wide format - which doesn't make much sense here). I'm not sure about the analysis though.

Comment: @AndyW If I do that, then how do I handle the probability distributions (which will be different) for every `videoId`/`topicId`?  How do I aggregate those together?